# How do I get a record type using nlapiLoadRecord?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, netsuite

I tried to get an item's type like inventory or non inventory using nlapiSearchRecord and nlapiLoadRecord function.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord(
        'item', search_id, null, 
        [
            new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'),
            new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid'),
        ]
    );


if (searchresults) {
    final_message += 'Search Results Length :' + searchresults.length;
    for (var i = 0; searchresults != null && i < searchresults.length; i++) {
        var record = nlapiLoadRecord(searchresults[i].getRecordType(),
            searchresults[i].getId() );

        nlapiLogExecution('log','recordtype', record.getFieldValue('type'));

        nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
    }
}
```

The log shows 'item', neither 'inventory' nor 'noninventory'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I improved the English, fixed the formatting of your code snippet so it renders properly, and added a missing brace at the end. Please see the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. I think the last sentence still needs work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the type directly from a search like:

```
var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('item', search_id, null, 
            [
                new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('type'),
            ]
        );
```

To get the same item type from an item record directly:

```
    var itemtype = record.getFieldValue('baserecordtype');
```

Alternatively, you might use, depending on your purpose:

```
    var otheritemtype = record.getFieldValue('itemtype');
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness help. It works perfectly :)